# Changing laravel 5.3 structure and public folder name

Tags: app-config, laravel-5.3, public

I uploaded the project to the server and this is the structure folders:

```
root
 - application (all laravel project)
 - public_html
```

I change already index.php in public_html:

```
require __DIR__.'/../application/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../application/bootstrap/app.php';
```

And like this is workin in my local server (with original public folder name of course) but it is not on remote server so I need to know what I have to do and set the new public folder.

I tried everything in [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5) nothing is working, maybe because I changed the structure. All the time I'm getting the error 500.

Comment: What specifically do you want to achieve? Your post isn't clear. Consider updating please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fix this issue..

In Laravel is not necessary to change the public folder name to make your project run, my issue was coming form .env file.

I got a value with blank spaces between string with no "", so I add them and finally, my projects runs.

Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution here is to make `public_html` a soft link to your Laravel `public` folder

From your root folder, try:

```
$ mv public_html public_html.bak
$ ln -s /path/to/root/application/public /path/to/root/public_html
```

The first command backs up your `public_html` folder and the second creates a link from your Laravel `public` directory to your server's `public_html`

Don't forget to swap out `/path/to/root` for the full path to your `root` directory